# Devise login with a user account that is created with respecte to other model

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a typical scenario ,
I have two model User and Student 
User has_one student 
Student belongs_to user.
So when i am creating a student at the same time i am creating a new user associated with student by 
user = @student.build_user
Then i can not login with that user acoount.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable #, :confirmable
  before_save :set_default_role

  attr_accessor :role, :password
  has_one :student_admission, :class_name => "Student", :foreign_key=>"user_id"


  private
  def set_default_role
    if self.new_record?
      self.admin, self.student, self.employee = false, false, false
      self.admin    = true if self.role == 'Admin'
      self.student  = true if self.role == 'Student'
      self.employee = true if self.role == 'Employee'
      self.parent = true if self.role == 'Parent'
    end

  end
end


class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  before_validation :create_user_and_validate

  def create_user_and_validate
    if self.new_record?
      user_record = self.build_user
      user_record.first_name = self.first_name
      user_record.last_name = self.last_name
      user_record.email = self.email.to_s
      user_record.password = self.admission_no.to_s + "123"
      user_record.role = 'Student'
      #user_record.email = self.email.blank? ? "" : self.email.to_s
      check_user_errors(user_record)
      return false unless errors.blank?
    else
      changes_to_be_checked = ['admission_no','first_name','last_name','email']
      check_changes = self.changed & changes_to_be_checked
      unless check_changes.blank?
        self.user.username = self.admission_no if check_changes.include?('admission_no')
        self.user.first_name = self.first_name if check_changes.include?('first_name')
        self.user.last_name = self.last_name if check_changes.include?('last_name')
        self.user.email = self.email if check_changes.include?('email')
        check_user_errors(self.user)
      end

    end
  end

  def check_user_errors(user)
    unless user.valid?
      user.errors.each{|attr,msg| errors.add(attr.to_sym,"#{msg}")}
    end
    user.errors.blank?
  end

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}"
  end

end
```

I want to know is this possible to loging in with such a user using devise.If it is then how.Please help as i am new to rails4 .
thanks

Comment: Hi,
is there any one to help with problem.

Comment: Are you sure the user is definitely saved in the database?  I would have thought the user validation would fail because devise would usually want user.password and user.password_confirmation to both be set and be equal as part of the user validation.